# Views not updating multiple records

Tags: drupal-views

I upgraded from Drupal CiviCRM 5.2 to 5.5 recently. Prior to the upgrade, I had a Views page that listed a table of custom fields (multiple records). The views was based on a "CiviCRM Contacts", and then I added each Civi field into the Views page.

What I noticed today is that if I deleted a record in the multiple records field in CiviCRM, the Views page still lists that record in the table. Similarly, if I added a new record in the multiple records, it shows up in CiviCRM but not in the Views. Very strange. Is anyone else having this problem?

I've cleanup caches, update paths (in CiviCRM), cleared the views cache, and also in Drupal (Run cron, Run a database update, flush all caches). The only error I see right now is below, but I'm not sure this is related to problem (I know this bug has already been reported):

```
Warning: array_combine(): Both parameters should have an equal number of elements in CRM_Contact_BAO_Relationship::buildRelationshipTypeOptions() (line 2222 of C:\xampp\htdocs\sites\all\modules\civicrm\CRM\Contact\BAO\Relationship.php).
```

Comment: can you clarify your versions using the tags and include your Drupal version. 4.2/4.5 are unsupported versions of CiviCRM - ideally you should be on 4.6.* (LTS) or 5.4.* (Stable) otherwise there's very minimal support around as not many people will be running older versions.

Comment: Sorry! I meant to say 5.2 and 5.4. I'll correct it!

Comment: Have you tried clearing Views cache? In Views, go to Settings, advanced and the Clear Views Cache.  Views cache is very persistent!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized that my Drupal database and CiviCRM were linked to different databases. I forgot to update the settings file during my testing.